# Objects from a compound query don't get pinned on iOS using parse api

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a compound query in a query for table method for PFQueryTableViewController class:

```
func baseQuery() -> PFQuery {
    let ownedChannels = PFQuery(className: "Channel").whereKey("owner", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    let subscribedPrivateChannels = PFQuery(className: "Channel").whereKey("subscribers", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([ownedChannels, subscribedPrivateChannels])
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    return query
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    return baseQuery().fromLocalDatastore()
}
```

Then later i use a refresh function to fetch data from the server:

```
func refreshLocalDataStoreFromServer() {
    baseQuery().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (parseObjects,  error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Found \(parseObjects!.count) parseObjects from server")
            // First, unpin all existing objects
            PFObject.unpinAllInBackground(self.objects as? [PFObject], block: { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    // Pin all the new objects
                    PFObject.pinAllInBackground(parseObjects, block: { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            // Once we've updated the local datastore, update the view with local datastore
                            self.shouldUpdateFromServer = false
                            self.loadObjects()
                        } else {
                            print("Failed to pin objects")
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("Couldn't get objects")
        }
    }
}
```

Then to refresh data in the localstore i use:

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)
    if self.shouldUpdateFromServer {
        self.refreshLocalDataStoreFromServer()
    } else {
        self.shouldUpdateFromServer = true
    }
}
```

`shouldUpdateFromServer` is a bool value initialized with true

This works with regular queries, in this case it successfully pins `ownedChannels` but doesn't pin channels from the second query.

When logging `parseObjects` in the `refreshLocalDataStoreFromServer` method all the query results are shown.

`subscribers` is a parse relation between channel and user objects.